# React Bootstrap - Button to be inline with text input with label overhead

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

My react bootstrap code below results in the submit button being out of line with the input fields which have labels overhead - Is there a way to get the submit button in line with the text fields

[image]

```
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formButton">
                    <Button>Submit</Button>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>
        </Form>
     );
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use boostrap's `d-flex` class. You will simply need `align-items-end` along with it:

```
      <Form>
        <Form.Row className="d-flex align-items-end">
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formButton">
            <Button>Submit</Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
      </Form>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-pasteur-vwewz?file=/src/App.js

Alternatively, you can use `mt-x` classes on the button and just push it down with the top margin, but I don't recommend that.